# How do i add class to the element?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

```
<?php
   $config = Mage::getStoreConfig('tab1/general/enabled');
   if(!$config):?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var priority = document.getElementById("y");
   priority.className += ' hide';
   });
   </script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<?php
    $config = Mage::getStoreConfig('tab1/general/enabled');
    if (!$config): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', afterDOMLoaded);
        } else {
            afterDOMLoaded();
        }

        function afterDOMLoaded(){
           var priority = document.getElementById("y");
           priority.className += ' hide';
        }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/43245774/5703627

Comment: Error -> Can not read property of className of Null.

Comment: Even i console.log(y),it eturns null...so how woud i add class to that element?

Comment: Please check if there really is an element with ID "y".

Comment: The element is generated by js which is rendered at the end,so  now i am writing this scritp inline, thats why the element that cought is null.

Comment: OK, just have to make sure that the code from above is run after element is added :)